# commands after try..catch don't work

Tags: c++, mfc

I have a method with try..catch.
the structure is like this:

```
try
{
 commands...

}
catch(...)
{
    ERROR(...);
}
if(m_pDoc->m_bS = FALSE ) // Check here if AutoLogout event occurred.
    StartCollect();
}
```

The program doesn't go into the catch section, but it also doesn't go into the if statement later.
What can be the problem? Why doesn't the program go to the if statement?

Thanks

Comment: what compiler/ide do you use?

Comment: @user641490 do you have a 'return' statement somewhere inside your try? Why don't you try to step into your code and see when it jumps outside your function?

Comment: visual studio 2005. I dob't have return.

Comment: Don't know if this is relevant, but the `try` statement is not closed (there is no closing `}` before the `catch` statement) and your `if` statement uses `=` instead of `==`.

Comment: It was the if.. so stupid and hard to see mistake! thanks :)

Comment: @user641490: that's why one should always compile his code with warnings enabled: it makes writing the code a bit more difficult but for the greater good !

Answer (score 6):

Your `if` statement is almost certainly wrong. You're assigning `FALSE` to `bSilenClose` and then checking if it (false) is true, which will cause the body of your `if` to never execute. In C++ the test for equality is `==`. Additionally as @Martin York points out, the trailing `;` will be treated as the body of your if. The code below in braces should, in fact, execute every time.

```
if(m_pDoc->m_bSilenClose = FALSE );
                         ^       ^^^^ This should not be there. (Empty statement after if)
                         ^
                         ^ Assigning FALSE (should be == to test)
                           Condition always FALSE (thus never executes empty statement.
```

Comment: Many compilers (for example g++ -Wall) have warnings for this, to help prevent the problem at compile time.

Comment: @Martin York Thanks for the catch, I didn't even notice the terminating `;`

Comment: @user641490: So from now on try to put the _constant_ value as the l-value of a comparison, if you do so, even if you forget to put "==" in the middle of the operands you will get a compile error and this will never happen again. some examples:
'if (FALSE == m_pDoc->m_bS) {
   /*something...*/
}
///
if (NULL == somePtr) {
   /*something*/
}'
By doing this, you won't get such logical errors but compile errors!

Comment: @user641490 - As Parsa said get into the habit of putting the constants on the left hand side of comparison operators eg:

`if(FALSE == myvariable)`

Sorry... seems a few have already given examples for this.

Comment: @Parsa Jamshidi, @Dennis I personally actually don't do this, as I find that `if` statements read more clearly/naturally when the variable is on the left. Most any compiler will warn on the assignment construction (you can use treat warnings as errors if you like), which is all you need to catch the cases where assignment is used incorrectly.

Comment: It's called yoda conditionals, if false the value is check it you must.

Answer (score 4):

`catch` will only be called if an exception occurs. As to why the stuff in the if statement isn't being called, either:

- your conditional statement is wrong
- your catch might be throwing an exception too (?)

Edit: just noticed this is C++.

Comment: Since when are there `finally` blocks in C++?

Comment: * you might not be catching the exception that's being thrown

Comment: No, I missed this was C++, amending post.

Comment: @André Caron: actually, if I remember well, Visual C++ had an extension to support the `__finally` keyword. See [this link](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/815662).

Comment: @ereOn: the `__finally` keyword is used for Microsoft' Structured Exception Handling, not C++ exceptions, anyways.

Answer (score 1):

What do you catch? Your error could be of another type than the error you try to catch. Also, the Catch might be throwing an exception.

Real code and a better description always help too ;)

Comment: While debuggin, i see that it doesn't go into the catch block. I updated the original message with real code.

Comment: While debugging does it go the the end of the try statement? Do your debugger show you what error is thrown ? Is it the same type as the one in your catch statement? Does the IF statement after the Try/Catch get evaluated?

Answer (score 0):

Go through the block of code in the debugger, line by line (use the F10 key). You should see that the code does indeed get to the `if` statement.

Comment: I ran debugger line by line. It doesn't go to the if statement. More than that, when I move the if statement into the try section, it works good. (it also doesn't go into catch). What should be the problem

Comment: What happens last in the try block - i.e. the last thing it does is `return`, `continue`, `break` etc.

Comment: @user641490 And posting the real code led to the solution... congratulations. The debugger still should have reached the `if` statement, even if it didn't go into it.

Answer (score 0):

You have a typo

```
if(m_pDoc->m_bSilenClose = FALSE );
```

should be:

```
if(m_pDoc->m_bSilenClose == FALSE );
```

Comment: Also notice the ';' at the end there.

Answer (score 0):

That's why i prefer doing

if ( FALSE == variable )

When comparing to a constant